# How do I start writing a high performance html editor with a non default UI on Windows that I can later port to Linux and Mac?

Tags: windows-7, windows, text-editors, window-manager, development

I want to know the best way to get a window to display non default UI elements while ultimately being multiplatform.  I am trying to create an HTML editor which is more reactive but also featuring a not so native UI appearance and being also a high performance browser which does not comply with normal standards of displaying extraneous things and running dumb scripts.
Also I am looking for information on html interpreters which can already toggle inline visibility within subsections of HTML code.  But just some pointers on how to approach the skinned UI multiplatform development problem would be legit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) Windows, Linux, MacOS

[image: NetBeans IDE 8]